# Multithreading network programming using python

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

I am trying to broadcast a Udp packet to all the device on my subnet and then i would like to wait for incoming clients to connect to my ip address. I already did a program where it broadcasts its ip address but before that i want to simply send a msg. My problem is both of them is not happening together say if broadcasting is occurred server doesn't wait for client. If i add the line listen to client first then it happens first but i want both to happen. I am new to multithreading and i think there is a small change needed for both to happen, Please post your suggestions and thanks

This is my server side program

```
import threading
import socket
from socket import *
class Broker():
   def broadcast(self,msg):
       self.sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
       host='192.168.1.255'
       port=10000
       address=host,port
       self.sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,1)
       msg='hi broadcast'
       self.sock.sendto(msg.encode(),(address))
   def __init__(self):
         self.sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
         self.sock.bind(('192.168.1.60', 10000))
         self.clients_list = []

   def talkToClient(self, ip):
           self.sock.sendto("ok".encode('utf-8'), ip)

   def listen_clients(self):
           while True:
               msg, client = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
               print (msg.decode())
               t = threading.Thread(None, self.talkToClient, None, (client,), None)
               t.start()
b = Broker()
b.listen_clients()
b.broadcast(msg='this os bros')
```

Comment: Broadcasting is a bad way to do anything, and it can get your program banned. The proper way to handle this is through multicasting. That way, only the interested hosts will be interrupted. All hosts are interrupted with a broadcast, even routers printers, etc.

Comment: The reason is i wanted to publish my ip to all the clients on my subnet so multicast is not i wanted unfortunately @Ron Maupin

Comment: So, you want to interrupt your router, managed switches, WAPs, printers, etc., too? That's what a broadcast does. Broadcast is so misused that it has been removed for IPv6, the next IP version, in favor of multicast. If you ever want to use broadcast, you need to rethink it.

Comment: yes for my later purposes, i need to mange switches and so on. This is part of a controller program where it has all these functionality of broadcasting,communication between clients and so on and thats why i prefer broadcasting.

Comment: You really didn't understand. The proper way to do this is to have the clients subscribe to a multicast group, and anything sent to that group will get it, but other devices not interested, will not. Multicast is a selective broadcast, only interrupting the hosts interested. Many businesses now will not consider applications that use broadcast, which is limited to a single layer-2 LAN. It is possible to route multicast in your network, but not broadcast. It is also foolish not to also use at least both IPv4 and IPv6, and you cannot broadcast with IPv6.

Comment: ok, I will consider your opinion and thanks.

Comment: I was wondering how will the client subscribe to a multicast group and why not broadcast is a good idea? what makes it so bad to use bc? @Ron Maupin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168679/discussion-between-user9371612-and-ron-maupin).